# Visual Studio 2017 fail to connect macOS virtual machine installed visual studio for mac and xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Below error I am getting when I am connecting the visual studio to my macOS. I am building an iphone app in Visual Studio on Win OS. When try to run the application it showing this error:

```
The Xcode License status couldn't be verified because the 'xcodebuild' tool has not been found on the connected MAC. Having Xcode installed and functional is necessary in order to build and run iOS apps, so please check that xcode is correctly installed and that the path specified under iOS Settings is correct.
```

see screenshot of error:

[image]
Logs:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingService|Information|0|Agent IDB 4.9.0.752 is running
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic xma/agent-status was received
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|IDB 4.9.0.752 started
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Starting registered Agents: ...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from AgentsStartingState to AgentsStartedState on 192.168.106.128 (192.168.106.128)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|The Agents have been started successfully
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Server State transition from AgentsStartedState to ValidatingState on 192.168.106.128 (192.168.106.128)
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Performing server validations against '192.168.106.128'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Validating Mac operating system version compatibility...
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching SubscribeAck message to flow ClientSubscribeFlow
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xma/message-status
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic xma/message-status was received
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic vs6604UmerF/response/xma/get-env-info
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic vs6604UmerF/response/xma/get-env-info was received
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Validating Xcode license state...
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xma/message-status
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic xma/message-status was received
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching SubscribeAck message to flow ClientSubscribeFlow
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xma/message-status
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic xma/message-status was received
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic vs6604UmerF/response/xvs/idb/4.9.0.752/get-xcode-location
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic vs6604UmerF/response/xvs/idb/4.9.0.752/get-xcode-location was received
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - Dispatching Publish message to flow PublishReceiverFlow and topic xma/message-status
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl|Information|0|Client vs6604UmerF - An application message for topic xma/message-status was received
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|Failed to execute '/bin/bash -c 'find "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin" -type f | grep xcodebuild'': ExitStatus = 1
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|find: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I have the same problem... xcodebuild is not even in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin"

Answer (score 9):

On your Mac:

1) Is `Xcode` installed?

- If not get it for the App Store or login with your Apple developer's account and download the Xcode `.xip` file from:

  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

2) Open the `Xcode.app` and accept the license if prompted

3) Optional: Run `xcode-select --install` to install the Xcode cmd-line tools and accept the license if prompted

4) Run `xcode-select -print-path` to ensure that the directory that it points to is the same one that the Xamarin iOS options in Visual Studio is set to, i.e.

```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation

Comment: My xcode path is /Users/umermhr/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer but visual studio xcode path is disable. Can't update the path in VS.

Comment: The Mac pairing needs to be active, then you can deselect "Use default Xcode path" and enter the one that you need.

Comment: Wait, so you need to change the path to XCode to pair to the Mac, but you can only change the path if you are paired to the Mac? That doesn't sound quite right, does it?

Comment: @ViníciusQueiroz The "pairing" is an `ssh` connection and thus to change the Xcode path, it needs that connection to verify the result, it is not building anything at the time, so yes, sounds right to me ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover I suppose you meant that the file format is .xip instead of .xib.

Comment: There is no xcodebuild in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin" in my case.

Comment: @thxmxx `xcodebuild` will exist at `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

Answer (score 9):

In my case the terminal command "xcode-select -print-path" told me that the XCode app was installed in the folder: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools" but adding this to the "Tools | Options | Xamarin | iOS Settings did not work.

I finally solved it by adding the Xcode path: /Applications/Xcode.app
[image: Pair to mac XCode path]

Comment: I got this error after updating to Visual Studio 2019 v16.9, this was the fix for me

Comment: Needs more up votes on this, as with @DuncanWatts I got starting after upgrade to version16.9 yesterday.  Wasted a good few hours before coming across this post

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This solved the problem for me as well after upgrading to VS 16.9. Although in my case  `xcode-select -print-path` gave `/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and I had to put in exactly that for the Xcode path setting in VS.

Answer (score 4):

If you recently updated Xcode, check the login in xcode Preferences->Accounts->signin

I had same issue, solved after successfully signed in with my apple ID.

In my case I have copied and installed xcode.xip file downloaded in colleague's mac
I had to remove that and update xcode from appstore.

Comment: Same experience as me.  Just upgraded from Xcode 10 -> 11.  Pairing worked with 10, but go the idb error after upgrading.  Opened new Xcode and logged in with my Apple Id and was good to go

Answer (score 3):

As @SushiHangover suggested, you must ensure "that the directory that points to XCode path is the same one in the Xamarin iOS options in Visual Studio", the problem is that in some cases you can't set it before establishing the connection (disabled)

[image: SDK path desabled]

The only solution is that case is to to move your Xcode.app to the default location which is the application folder, and move the command line tools to the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - been lost for ages, trying all sorts. Turns out that although my Xcode was in the default location, i had installed the xcode-beta.app

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue by resetting the commandline tools from Terminal using the command:
sudo xcode-select --reset

This command changed my default path to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools. The connection started working after that.

Comment: This worked for me with reinstalled machine, using XCode 12.4 and Visual Studio 2019 16.9.2 (Windows) .